# Ludo game board in java

Tags: java

[image]

How to I write code to this board without using an array? 
I tried, but I did not get the right result. It should be with functions, loops and conditional structures. Row=11, column=11.

```
public static void board(int size) {
    for (int i=1; i<=size;i++){
        for (int j=1; j<=size; j++){
            if (i==6 && j==6){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else if ( i==5 || i==7 || j==5 || j==7 || i==6 && j==1 || i==6 && j==11 ||
                    i==1 && j==6 || i==11 && j==6){
                if (i==6 && j==7 || i==5 && j==6 || i==6 && j==5 || i==7 && j==6 ){
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print("o");
            }
            else if (i==6 || j==6 ) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    board(11);
}
```

Comment: I think you can make the main course as single dimensional array. The internal 4 paths as four more arrays.

Comment: Also, I strongly encourage you to use temporary variables for that first `if` statement (or, at least, parentheses). Right now it's very hard to tell what the actual result will be, and it's ambiguous what you're trying to achieve with it.

Comment: @chuckskull The OP says that they want to do it **without** using arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print it like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
static void printLudoBoard(int size) {
    if (size < 5 || size % 2 != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size must be odd and at least 5 (got " + size + ")");
    final String path = "o", goalPath = ".", goalCenter = " ";
    int armLength = (size - 3) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < armLength; i++)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(armLength) + path + (i == 0 ? path : goalPath) + path);
    System.out.println(path.repeat(armLength + 1) + goalPath + path.repeat(armLength + 1));
    System.out.println(path + goalPath.repeat(armLength) + goalCenter + goalPath.repeat(armLength) + path);
    System.out.println(path.repeat(armLength + 1) + goalPath + path.repeat(armLength + 1));
    for (int i = armLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(armLength) + path + (i == 0 ? path : goalPath) + path);
}
```

<sup>*1) `repeat()` was added in java 11. If they are teaching you a Java version before that, go get your tuition money back, and go to a school that doesn't teach ancient out-dated coding. Or implement you own `repeat()` helper method.*</sup>

**`printLudoBoard(11)`**

```
    ooo
    o.o
    o.o
    o.o
ooooo.ooooo
o.... ....o
ooooo.ooooo
    o.o
    o.o
    o.o
    ooo
```

**`printLudoBoard(15)`**

```
      ooo
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
ooooooo.ooooooo
o...... ......o
ooooooo.ooooooo
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
      o.o
      ooo
```

Comment: I have not come to the voting phase yet. I can't do it right now because I just opened it. I'm sorry. However I will do it when it opens. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You're using two separate loops to do what you should be doing with one loop (and you need to print the spaces, too).  The problem is that you're figuring out where the characters should go, but you're not filling in the spaces between.

For instance, say you wanted to print on columns 1, 3, and 8, so you wrote:

```java
for (j = 1; j <= 11; j++) {
    if (j == 1 || j == 3 || j == 8) {
        System.out.println("o");
    }
}
```

It's just going to print `ooo` because there aren't any spaces in between.

So, you probably want something like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args ){
    for (int i=1; i<=11;i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 11; j++) {
            if (i == 5 || i == 7 || j == 5 || j == 7 || i == 6 && j == 1 || i == 6 && j == 11 ||
                    i == 1 && j == 6 || i == 11 && j == 6) {
                System.out.print("o");
            } else if (i==6 || j==6) {
                System.out.print(".");
            } else {
                // Nothing should be here: print a space
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I think you need to fix the numbers in the logic a bit, because this prints:

```
    ooo
    o.o
    o.o
    o.o
ooooooooooo
o...o.o...o
ooooooooooo
    o.o
    o.o
    o.o
    ooo
```

which isn't quite your desired output, but this should set you in the right direction.

Comment: Glad it helped, if you feel this answer is correct please upvote and/or accept it so that others can find it more easily :-)